# How to find a watch in scope.$$watchers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularjs and need to find the watch of the `ng-repeat`, because I need `ng-repeat` to stop working from a specific point. this my code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to find the watcher of the `ng-repeat`. If I go to `scope.$parent.$$watchers[x]` and perform `splice` the watch is removed, but how can I find the specific watch?

Comment: What do you mean by, "because I need ng-repeat to stop working from a specific point"? Do you want to only repeat a subset of the items?

Comment: I want it to stop working after scope.$last is set. I need a bind once  ng-repeat

Comment: ng-repeat="item in items" <div ng-if="!$last">{{item.name}}</div> like that is not enough

Comment: @Ben2307 Do you just need `ngRepeat` to show the data once, then never  update the view again?

Comment: @YeLiu Yes. I also want to remove the watch from the $$watchers.

Comment: @Ben2307 Why do you have to remove watcher?

Comment: I got a lot of ng-repeater that I need only to run once. To increase performance I want to remove all the unneeded watchers.

Comment: Why dont you just write an own directive that does exactly this? Could even be on top of ng-repeat by just taking the object to repeat and using angular.copy to break the reference....

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to find the watch (see explanation below), but you can achieve what you wish by use the following directive

```
app.directive('repeatStatic',
     function factory() {
      var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : true, // this isolates the scope from the parent
        priority : 1001, // ng-repeat has 1000
        compile : function compile() {
          return {
            pre : function preLink(tElement, tAttrs) {
            },
            post : function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller,
                transcludeFn) {
              scope.$apply(); // make the $watcher work at least once
              scope.$$watchers = null; // remove the $watchers
            },
          };
        }
      };

      return directiveDefinitionObject;
     }
    );
```

and its usage is

```
<ul>
  <li repeat-static ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

See http://plnkr.co/k9BTSk as a working example.

The rational behind is that 
the angular directive **ng-repeat** directive uses internal function $watchCollection to add a self created listener that watchs the *items* object. Since the listener is a function created during the process, and is not keep anywhere as reference, there is no good way to correctly identify which function to remove from the $$watchers list.

**However** a new scope can be forced into the ng-repeat by using an attribute directive, in this way the $$watchers added by ng-repeat are isolated from the parent scope. Thus, we obtain full control of the scope.$$watchers. Immediate after the ng-repeat uses the function that fills the value, the $$watchers are safe to be removed.
This solution uses hassassin's idea of cleaning the $$watchers list.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fork of Angular that lets you keep the watch in the `$$watchers` but skip it most of the time. Unlike writing a custom directive that compiles your HTML it lets you use normal Angular templates on the inside, the difference is that once the inside is fully rendered the watches will not get checked any more.

Don't use it unless you really genuinely need the extra performance because it can have surprising behaviour.

Here it is:

https://github.com/r3m0t/angular.js/tree/digest_limit

Here's the directive you can use with it (`new-once`):

https://gist.github.com/r3m0t/9271790

If you want the page to never update you can use `new-once=1`, if you want it to sometimes update you can use `new-once=updateCount` and then in your controller run `$scope.updateCount++;` to trigger an update.

More information: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce/issues/42#issuecomment-36354087

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have dealt with this in the past is that I created a custom directive that copies the logic of the built in `ngRepeat` directive but never sets up the watches. You can see an example of this [here](https://gist.github.com/akearney/9624142), which was created from the `ngRepeat` code from version 1.1.5.

The other way, as you mentioned was to remove it from `$$watchers` of a scope, which is a little stranger since it accesses a private variable.

How this could be done is that you create a custom directive on the repeat to remove the watch that is the repeat. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuN4s/1/) that does this. It basically just on the last element of the repeat clears the parent watch (which is the one on data)

```
if (scope.$last) {
    // Parent should only be the ng-repeat parent with the main watch
    scope.$parent.$$watchers = null;
}
```

This can be modified to fit your specific case.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to put the `bindonce` directive on your `ng-repeat`.

https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Comment: That doesn't help, because it still leaves the ng-repeat watcher on the collection.

Comment: Maybe you should run `$scope.itemsToDisplay = $scope.items` or `$scope.itemsToDisplay = angular.copy($scope.items)` so that you can update `$scope.items` without your `ng-repeat` triggering. Use `itemsToDisplay` in your template.

Comment: It's not the triggering that is the problem. It's the unused watches

Comment: How long is your `$scope.items` array? It shouldn't be a problem. If you are talking about the watches *inside* the `ng-repeat`, `bindonce` fixes that.

Comment: It's the watcher of the ng-repeat itself that I want to remove

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Unless your array is very very long it won't have an effect on performance. Use Batarang to check whether that particular watch is slowing down your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need angular dual-binding, have you tried a custom directive with a complie function where you construct HTML yourself by creating DOM from scratch without any angular dual-binded mechanisms ?

Comment: I need what ng-repeat gives me out of the box. Things like filtering and sorting